# CSS - Change button background color on hover

Tags: html, css

I need change button background color on hover.

My CSS on jsfiddle:
[CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/yMG2Q/3/)

My HTML :

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg' value='test'/>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yMG2Q/3/)

Comment: this is not your code, you ripped this from some website and expect us to alter it as per your needs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve it in the following way. This solution will work if you add this class at the bottom of your CSS.

```
.btn:hover
{
background-image:none;
background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

If you keep this class in top of the other styles, you need to use `important` keyword to overcome with other styles like below.

```
.btn:hover
{
background-image:none !important;
background-color:#ff00ff !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yMG2Q/6/)

Answer (score 2):

you might use this solution as `!important` make the CSS invalid. In this case all the `type= button` which have `.btn` class will only affected.

```
input[type="button"].btn:hover{background:red;}
```

Comment: @user3272321 I would suggest you to not used  the `!important` in your CSS file as in w3c validator your CSS file will be failed. you can try the above approach. much better way to handle.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve using the below

```
.btn:hover{
//apply styles here
}
```

Comment: his question is what style he need to apply.

Comment: Suresh, I went through his fiddle, I didn't see any .btn:hover there, if we guide him to use the :hover , he can do whatever style he want to do when hovering.

Answer (score 0):

this is really easy, you just have to add the css selector :hover

for example:

```
.btn-success:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #51a351;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use :hover with the class for the mouse hover event. Like if you want you can use:

```
btn:hover {
   color:blue; 
}
```

best of luck

Comment: OP is talking about background-color not text color.