# How to change Hover button color?

Tags: html, css

Here's a link change color for hover effect  .
hover effect code not workig for change a color

below css i have already added but not working

```
a::hover{color:red;}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898781/how-can-i-change-a-buttons-color-on-hover or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819910/css-change-button-background-color-on-hover/24819975 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270520/changing-hover-color-css

Comment: Use a:hover instead of a::hover

Comment: One colon... **not two**.

Comment: I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check below css for hover effect .

```
a:hover{color:red;}
```